# WSDL address containing underscores throws an error.Error:- toLowerCase() in java.net.HostPortrange fails on special characters

Tags: java, web-services, wsdl, webservice-client

In NetBeans 8 running on JDK 8u25 When i was adding a Web Service Client. I inserted WSDL address, but the environment constantly returned "Problem with downloading wsdl(Web Service Description Language) or schema file", although it worked in other applications.
The problem is that the address contained underscores and the error is invoked by the IllegalArgumentException("Invalid characters in hostname") that was thrown by toLowerCase() method in java.net.HostPortrange.
toLowerCase() checks the characters of an address and if they are not within [a-z0-9A-Z.-] an exception is thrown even though also other characters are valid in URL.

Please provide me any idea for the resolution of this problem.

Answer (score 0):

It's a bug in JDK 8 b177. It is fixed in b122 Please refer below link:

https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8029354